# How do I change values in a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R. My variable called numoftrends is currently defined as 10 (this could change to any number) and I have created 2nd vector called df_lines of 1:10 and line_types of 2:6. what I would like to do is to replace all the values in the df_lines with the values of line_types.

```
df_lines 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

line_types 
#2 3 4 5 6
```

When I replace the value of df_lines., this is how it should look like

```
df_lines
# 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6
```

Now depending on the numoftrends, the values in df_lines will vary. another example if my numoftrends <- 8

My df_lines should look like this

```
2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4
```

How do I code this in R?

Here is my R code

```
 numoftrends <- 10
 df_lines <- c(1:numoftrends)
 line_types <- c(2:6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numoftrends <- 10
df_lines <- c(1:numoftrends)
line_types <- c(2:6)
rep(line_types, length.out=length(df_lines))
# > rep(line_types, length.out=length(df_lines))
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6
```

The other example:

```
numoftrends <- 8
df_lines <- 1:numoftrends
line_types <- 2:6
rep(line_types, length.out=length(df_lines))
# > rep(line_types, length.out=length(df_lines))
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

```
numoftrends <- 10 # or length(df_lines)
rep_len(line_types, numoftrends)
```

Comment: Appreciate your time G Cocca. This is what I am  looking for.